# How do I select all slotted by name?

Tags: css, web-component, custom-component, shadow-dom, slot

I am dealing with this situation...

```
<template>
  <slot name="thing"></slot>
  <slot name="other"></slot>
</template>
```

and an implementation like

```
<custom-element>
  <div slot="thing"> Thing 1 </div>
  <div slot="thing"> Thing 2 </div>
  <div slot="other"> Thing 3 </div>
</custom-element>
```

How do I use a CSS query to affect both Thing 1 & Thing 2 but excludes Thing 3?

Comment: `[slot="thing"]{ border: 2px dashed #f00; }` [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: So would thing be like `:head[slot="thing"]` given shadow dom?

Comment: I'm not sure about the web-component implementation... I thought you were just looking for the css-selector... `slot[name="thing"]` maybe?

Comment: The things I've found useful to try for web-components: in outside CSS `:defined`, `[slot=...]`, and for the CSS inside the component, `:host`, `::slotted()`, `slot[name=...]`.

Comment: Sorry meant host

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Shadow DOM `<style>` tag, you can apply CSS styles directly to the `<slot>` element as @admcfajn suggeded in its second comment:

```
slot[name="thing"] { .. }
```

But if you want to target an element from the light DOM when it's inserted in the Shadow DOM through a `<slot>` element, you should use the `::slotted(`) pseudo-element function.

```
::slotted( div[slot="thing"] ) { color: green }
```

will color in red the text inside the `<div>` with the attribute `slot="name"`.

**Important:** the second solution is preferred, because the CSS from the light DOM has priority. Thereforce style inherited from the light DOM will override style from the slot element. See the example with `background-color` below:

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } ).innerHTML = tpl.innerHTML
  }
} )
```

```css
body { background-color: lightblue }
```

```html
<template id=tpl>
  <style>
    ::slotted( [slot=thing] ) { background-color: green }
    slot[name="other"] { background-color: red }
  </style>
  <slot name="thing"></slot>
  <slot name="other"></slot>
</template>

<custom-element>
  <div slot="thing"> <div>Thing 1 </div></div>
  <div slot="thing"> Thing 2 </div>
  <div slot="other"> Thing 3 </div>
</custom-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to Supersharp his answer:

> You *can* style **slotted** content with **global** CSS

`div` elements (in lightDOM) with a `slot` **attribute** are part of the main DOM

**Global** styles applied to those elements are/maintain applied **when slotted inside shadowDOM**

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML=`<slot name="thing"></slot>`
                  +`<slot name="other"></slot>`
                  +`<slot></slot>`
  }})
```

```css
[slot] { background-color: lightblue }
```

```html
<style id=GlobalStyle>
  [slot]:not([slot="other"]){
    background:green;
  }
</style>

<button onclick=GlobalStyle.disabled=!GlobalStyle.disabled>
TOGGLE GlobalStyle
</button>

<custom-element>
  <div slot="thing"> Thing 1 </div>
  <HR>
  <div slot="thing"> Thing 2 </div>
  <div slot="other"> Thing 3 </div>
  <div slot="none" > Thing 4 </div>
  <b>
    <div> Thing 5 </div>
  </b>
  <div slot="thing"> Thing 6 </div>
</custom-element>
```

#### Notes

- `Thing 6` is slotted before `Thing 3`, because slot `thing` is defined before slot `other`
- `Thing 4` is in lightDOM but not slotted, because it does not have a matching slotname
- All other lightDOM content (especially note the `HR`) is injected in the *unnamed* slot